# Добавить в строке к именам пользователей хештеги как в соц.сетях

Tags: php

Есть такая строка:

```
$str = "Nastya, Elena Babanina, Oleg, Gosha Tytkin";
```

Нужно заменить пробелы на "_" и поставить перед каждым именем "#" так что бы получилось:

```
echo "#Nastya, #Elena_Babanina, #Oleg, #Gosha_Tytkin";
```

Буду очень признателен за помощь

Comment: `echo 
    implode(', ', array_map(function($e) {
        return '#' . str_replace(' ', '_', $e);
    }, explode(', ', $str)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = ",Nastya, Elena Babanina, ,, Oleg , Gosha Tytkin";

$array = array_map(
    function ($nick) {
        return '#'.str_replace(' ', '_', trim($nick));
    },

    preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);

echo '<pre>', implode(', ', $array);
```